# Eliminate duplicated elements from a non-ordered array

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Write the function:
int different(int input[], int size, int **vetout);
while given an array input of integers with dimension size creates a vector in dynamic memory that contains all the elements of input repeated once. Function different returns the size of the modified array.
My problem is that i get the segmentation fault error when i compile the program. Can anyone help me please.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

int different(int input[],int size, int **vetout);

int main(){
    int input[]={1,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,4};
    int size=10; int n; int i; int *vetout;
    n = different(input, size, &vetout);
    printf("The size is : %d", n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){printf("The array is : %d",vetout[i]);}
    return 0;
}

int different(int input[],int size, int **vetout){
    int i=0;int j,k;
    while(i<size){
        j=i+1;
        while(j<size){
            if(input[i]==input[j]){
                for(k=j;k<=size;k++){
                    input[k]=input[k+1]; size--;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    *vetout=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    printf("The size is : %d",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){*vetout[i]=input[i];}

    return size;
}
```

Comment: while loop is too complicated. You need to compare input[i] with all input[0...i-1], and add to vetout if the value is new. Of course, vetout should be allocated before the loop. Don't change original input array.

Comment: In `for(k=j;k<=size;k++){input[k]=input[k+1]; size--;}` the limit `k<=size` can make `input[k]` index outside the array bound. Even if you changed that to `k<size` the following `input[k+1]` can be indexing outside the array bound too.

Comment: You should use a different variable than `size` for the output, because `size--` is shortening the input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your function, feel free to use it as a base - this is not the best solution for your issue - the comments preety much covered your issues in the original implementation

hope this will serve as a guideline

```
int different(int input[],int size, int **vetout){

    int count = 0;
    int found, i, j;
    *vetout = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

    for ( i=0; i<size ; i++ ) {
        // this loop will iterate on each element of the array
        // and check if it was already listed
        found = 0;
        for ( j=0; j < count ; j++ ) {
            //this loop checks if the value was already set in the output vector
            if ( *(*vetout+j) == input[i] ) {
                found = 1;
            }
        }

        //if it was not set - then set it and increse the index 'count'
        if ( !found )
        {
            *(*vetout+ (count++)) = input[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The size is : %d\n", count);

    return count;
}
```